# Download a CSV to a file containing the current timestamp

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to download a CSVfile from an API, I would like to save it in a folder with a timestamp so distinguish it from each of the previous files within the folder.

The below script is where I am up to but I am hitting a block whereby the file doesn't appear to be saving. Is there something fundamentally wrong with the script.

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://www.url.com/csvdownload"
((Get-Date)).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')) export-csv C:\Users\me\Documents\folder\sub-folder\test_output_file_((Get-Date)).csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably *don't* need to use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet since you are already download a CSV. Just format the filename to `<timestamp>.csv` and save it:

```
$fileName = '{0:MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss}.csv' -f (Get-Date)
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://www.url.com/csvdownload", $fileName)
```